# Vue 2 ciclo no funciona en componente

Tags: javascript, vue.js

La idea es recorrer la colección de mensajes (`messages`) obtenidas del backend mediante AJAX y mostrarlos en el HTML, para ésto uso `v-for`. Al parecer los parámetros regresados por data no los está recibiendo el template.

**Template**

```
<template lang="html">
    <a v-for="message in messages" href="#">
        <div class="user-img">
            <img src="/assets/plugins/images/users/pawandeep.jpg" alt="user" class="img-circle">
            <span class="profile-status away busy offline online pull-right"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mail-contnet">
            <h5 vue-text="message.title"></h5>
            <span class="mail-desc">Content</span>
            <span class="time">Date</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      messages: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this
      .$http.get('/api/messages')
      .then(response => this.messages = response.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Alfredo. Te comento que el código lo debes poner aquí para que sea más práctico y sencillo para la gente que te ayuda o visitantes poder verlo. Por esta vez lo he hecho por ti, recuerda hacerlo en tu próxima pregunta.

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta, la información que trae el módulo `$http` de [`vue-resource`](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) está en el atributo `body` del objeto `Response`. Es decir, deberías reemplazar `response.data` con `response.body`.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        messages: []
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.$http.get('/api/messages')
        .then(response => {
            this.messages = reponse.body
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas declarar el 'this'(self) fuera de la llamada ajax.

```
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
            messages: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        var self = this
        this.$http.get('/api/messages')
            .then(response => {
                self.messages = reponse.body
            })
    }
```

Comment: No es así, porque está utilizando una función flecha y estas no recuerdan ningún contexto. Si en lugar de usar una función flecha hubiese usado una función normal, entonces sí sería necesario almacenar el contexto en una variable o en su defecto usar `.bind`.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración!

Answer (score 0):

El problema se soluciono haciendo uso de las "props", eso era todo. Muchas gracias por su ayuda a todos.

```
export default {
  props() {
      return ['messages']
  },
  data() {
    return {
      messages: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this
      .$http.get('/api/messages')
      .then(response => this.messages = response.data);
    }
  }
}
```